# Upper bound on output of halting transducer

Tags: turing-machines, computability

My question is simply this: is it possible to upper bound the output length of a **halting** turing machine? I.e., is there a function $f$ such that for every halting machine $M$ and every input $x$ we have $|M(x)| \in O(f(|x|))$?

On the one hand, it seems like yes because every halting machine will leave some finite string on the tape so surely each machine has a longest output given all inputs of length $n$. But on the other hand, it feels like no because whatever bound $O(f(n))$ you give me, I could build a machine that writes $f(n)$ on the tape $f(f(n))$ many times or something. So I'm a bit confused...

For comparison, clearly a P time/space machine can only output strings of length $poly(n)$. Is this cutoff simply the time/space complexity? So what's the smallest class with unbounded output length?

Comment: Your question is unclear because you wrote down the quantifiers the wrong way around. You don't want "for every input is there a function such that ...?" but rather "is there a function such that for every input ...?" I rephrased the question the way I *think* you meant it. If it's wrong, please formulate it the way you want it (but precisely, and paying attention to the order of quantifiers).

Comment: Yes that's what I meant - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes! Fix your favorite flavour of Turing machines (for instance: non-deterministic Turing machines with a single tape), and fix both the input and output alphabets. Then for each $s \in \mathbb{N}$, there are finitely many machines with $s$ states (up to relabeling the states). Also, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there are finitely many inputs of size $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so the function
$$
f\colon (s, n) \mapsto \max\{|\mathcal{M}(x)| \mid x \text{ is an input of size $n$ and $\mathcal{M}$ is a halting machine with $s$ states}\}
$$
is well-defined.
Then, let $g \colon n \mapsto f(n,n)$.

**Claim:** If $\mathcal{M}$ is a halting Turing machine, then $|\mathcal{M}(x)| \in \mathcal{O}(g(|x|))$.

*Proof:* Let $s$ be its number of states. Then for each input $x$, we have
$|\mathcal{M}(x)| \leq f(s, |x|)$. Whenever $|x| \geq s$, we have $f(s,|x|) \leq f(|x|, |x|) = g(|x|)$ , and hence for every halting machine, there is an $n_0$ (namely its number of states) such that for every input $x$ of size $n \geq n_0$, $|\mathcal{M}(x)| \leq g(n)$.

Interestingly, the exact same proof works if you replace "size of the input" by "number of steps", and so there is a function $g'$ such that for any halting Turing machine $\mathcal{M}$, the function
$$n \mapsto \text{maximal nb of steps executed by $\mathcal{M}$ on a input of size $n$}$$
is a $\mathcal{O}(g')$.